# initializing a 2d array, each element is a list?

Tags: arrays, matlab

So, what I am trying to do is create a variable that holds 50 lists/arrays. Accessing an element in this variable would return one of the lists.  If there are no elements at a given index, I would like it to return [].

My logic to initialize this would be something like:

```
spectrum_map=[];
for n=1:spectrum_blocks
    spectrum_map=[spectrum_map,[]];
end
```

However, after doing so, I simply get an empty matrix:

```
spectrum_map =

     []
```

What I want to see is something like:

```
spectrum_map =

     []  []  []  []  [] ....
```

That way, if I were to access spectrum_map(2), I would see that it is empty.  However, instead I would get an error that the index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Is there some other way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the effect you're looking for if you use a cell array instead of a matrix.

```
spectrum_map = cell( 1, 50 );
spectrum_map{50}

ans =

     []
```

If you need to convert back to a matrix later (to perform some math on it, for instance) you can use the `cell2mat` function.